# How to retrieve the current selection of an NSPopUpButtonCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsmenu, nspopupbuttoncell

I am using an `NSPopUpButtonCell` in an `NSTableView`. The popup button has a binding to an `NSArray`  property offered by the `ApplicationDelegate`. When I select a menu item of the popup button I expect to retrieve the **current selection or its index**. I added an IBAction to being informed and also set up an `NSMenuDelegate`. **Both return index = 0 at all times.**

```
// indexOfSelectedItem is always 0.
NSInteger indexOfSelectedItem = [m_popUpButtonCell indexOfSelectedItem];
```

I created an [example project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/NSPopUpButtonCell) with the aforementioned configuration. Hopefully you can clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [Implementing To-One Relationships Using Pop-Up Menus](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/onerelation.html) answered my question.
**I updated the example project**.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you explain what you did? I set the NSPopUpButtonCell's action to a method that simply checks for the selected index ([thePopUp indexOfSelectedItem]), but it keeps returning 0. Do I have to learn how to use bindings?